# FastAPI + Selenium to convert HTML to PDF pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, fastapi

I'm attempting to develop a REST service that will render HTML to a PDF file on demand. I have explored multiple options but I have yet to find one that renders a PDF document as perfectly as Chrome itself. So I thought to wrap `Selenium` and `Chromedriver` in a FastAPI by leveraging the great library from `pyhtml2pdf`.

However, I found that by using this library, it would invoke a new instance of Chrome with every API call. As you can imagine, this was slow per call to the endpoint and required a lot of memory.

So I borrowed some of the code from this library and made a single instance that would be created upon launching the service and the endpoint would use the browser driver as a global object.

This resulted in a 10x increase in speed and far reduced memory. Can anyone see any downside to wrapping Selenium/Chrome in a FastAPI endpoint? What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
import sys
import json
import base64
import os
import re
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

webdriver_options = Options()
webdriver_prefs = {}
driver = None

webdriver_options.add_argument("--headless")
webdriver_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
webdriver_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
webdriver_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
webdriver_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = webdriver_prefs

webdriver_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=webdriver_options)

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    global driver
    print("Staring PDF service")
    yield
    driver.quit()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/get_pdf/")
def get_pdf(serial: str):
    global driver

    url = 'https://example.com/templates/serial.php?serial=' + serial

    html = requests.get(url)
    local_html_file = serial + "_htmldata.html"
    f = open(local_html_file, "w")
    f.write(html.text)
    f.close()

    local_pdf_file = serial + ".pdf"

    driver.get(f'file:///home/ubuntu/pdf2/'+local_html_file)

    calculated_print_options = {
        "landscape": False,
        "displayHeaderFooter": False,
        "printBackground": True,
        "preferCSSPageSize": True,
        "marginLeft": 0.4,
        "marginRight": 0.5,
        "scale": 0.75,
    }

    result = __send_devtools(
        driver, "Page.printToPDF", calculated_print_options)

    with open(local_pdf_file, "wb") as file:
        file.write(base64.b64decode(result["data"]))

    os.remove(local_html_file)

    return "done"

def __send_devtools(driver, cmd, params={}):
    resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command_and_get_result" % driver.session_id
    url = driver.command_executor._url + resource
    body = json.dumps({"cmd": cmd, "params": params})
    response = driver.command_executor._request("POST", url, body)

    if not response:
        raise Exception(response.get("value"))

    return response.get("value")


# Run the FastAPI application using uvicorn server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("pdf_rest:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```